# How can I animate the stretching of a sprite over time?

Tags: xna-4.0, animation

My goal is to find the function to stretch a sprite like my example below, and then get it to animate during a certain time. It is like an interpolation, where the starting point is the original image, and the final point is the stretched image. Any idea?

Here is an example, hope it is clear.

[image]

Comment: Your question is a combination of a few simple techniques. [Scaling a sprite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb194913.aspx) and [changing a value over time](http://www.crappycoding.com/2011/06/animation-with-timers/). You may find it useful in the future to break apart your problem into smaller problems, that are more generic and easily searchable.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found very useful your links and your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SpriteBatch` class's `Draw` method has [an overload that allows you to specify a scale factor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff433989.aspx).  Thus, to render a sprite in a stretched frame, do something like:

```
// Scale the sprite 50% along X (like in your example).
var scale = new Vector2(0.5f, 1.0f);

// Draw the sprite with that scale. 
spriteBatch.Draw(
  texture,
  position,
  null,
  Color.White,
  0.0f,
  Vector2.Zero, 
  scale,
  SpriteEffects.None,
  0
);
```

To achieve an animation of this effect, store your scale factor somewhere (a member in your `Game` class would be simple to start with), and update it over time in your game's `Update` method. The `Update` method gives you a [`GameTime` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.aspx) containing [the elapsed time since the last update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.gametime.elapsedgametime.aspx). Every update, adjust your scaling factor by the amount you want to scale per second using the `TotalSeconds` member of the elapsed time span object.